# Arithmetic operations on NumericArrays

Tags: performance-tuning, undocumented, arithmetic, numeric-array

Currently, `NumericArray`s are directly supported by the most important array-related functions, what makes them a very attractive data structure for implementing highly efficient algorithms. Here is a (possibly incomplete) list of functions from the current Documentation which directly support `NumericArray`s as **input *and* output** data structure:

`Part`,
`Take`,
`Drop`,
`Flatten`,
`Join`,
`FunctionCompile`,
`NetEncoder`.

Other functions which directly support `NumericArray`s according to the Documentation include:

`Dimensions`,
`Length`,
`ArrayDepth`,
`NumericArrayQ`,
`NumericArrayType`,
`Normal`,
`Image`,
`Image3D`,
`Audio`.

Testing shows that `Total` also accepts `NumericArray` as input:

```
Total[NumericArray[{1, 2, 3}, "UnsignedInteger8"]]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

But what is missing is the support even for the basic arithmetic operations on `NumericArray`s. For example, an attempt to add two arrays of the same type and shape returns unevaluated:

```
NumericArray[{1, 2, 3}, "UnsignedInteger8"] + NumericArray[{3, 4, 5}, "UnsignedInteger8"]
```

[image: screenshot]

There is undocumented built-in package `` "NumericArrayUtilities`" `` with the Description

> Utilities for doing high-performance numeric computations.

It includes several utilities:

```
Needs["NumericArrayUtilities`"]
Names["NumericArrayUtilities`*"] // Length
```

> ```
> 38
> ```

But it seems they don't offer the desired functionality either.

My question:

**How can I perform basic arithmetic operations on `NumericArray`s without converting them to usual arrays?**

I'm most interested in *subtraction* and *addition*.

Comment: I think you need to compile a function with `FunctionCompile` to do that.

Comment: It would count as a solution if there is a package/paclet adding such functionality. It is really strange that I can't find anything...

Answer (score 13):

It seems like no one answered this yet, so let me elaborate a little on my comment. A simple example of using `FunctionCompile` to add `NumericArray`s would be:

```
n1 = NumericArray[{1, 2, 3}, "UnsignedInteger8"];
n2 = NumericArray[{3, 4, 5}, "UnsignedInteger8"];
add = FunctionCompile[
   Function[
    {
     Typed[x, TypeSpecifier["NumericArray"]["UnsignedInteger8", 1]],
     Typed[y, TypeSpecifier["NumericArray"]["UnsignedInteger8", 1]]
     },
    x + y
    ]
   ];
add[n1, n2]
Normal[%]
```

> {4, 6, 8}

So as you can see, this is a bit tedious because you need to define a new function for each type of array. I believe that there is work ongoing in the compiler team to have polymorphic types that would make this easier, but for the time being you can do something like:

```
Clear[addArrays];
addArrays[type_String, depth_Integer] := (
   addArrays[type, depth] = FunctionCompile[
     Function[
      {
       Typed[x, TypeSpecifier["NumericArray"][type, depth]],
       Typed[y, TypeSpecifier["NumericArray"][type, depth]]
       },
      x + y
      ]
     ]
   );
addArrays[n1_?NumericArrayQ, n2_?NumericArrayQ] := With[{
   types = NumericArrayType /@ {n1, n2},
   depths = ArrayDepth /@ {n1, n2}
   },
  If[And[SameQ @@ types, SameQ @@ depths],
   addArrays[types[[1]], depths[[1]]][n1, n2]
   ]
  ];

addArrays[NumericArray[{1, 2}, "UnsignedInteger64"], NumericArray[{2, 2}, "UnsignedInteger64"]]
```

Comment: Thank you, it is helpful. The main drawback of `FunctionCompile` is significant compilation time: runing the first function from your answer in a fresh kernel of version 13.0.1 takes 12.2 seconds on my machine, successive runs with slight modifications of the function body (e.g. replace `x + y` with `x - y`) take about 1.7 seconds. `Compile` by default works much faster, but it seemingly doesn't support `NumericArray` at all.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Correct, the compilation time for a function is quite slow and loading the compiler code in a fresh kernel session is also very slow. That said: after compilation is done, you have a function that's basically as fast as your processor will allow. `Compile` is old functionality that only works with packed arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have anything to add with respect to arithmetic on the NumericArray objects, which I feel Sjoerd covered well with their answer, but since OP asked about the package, I thought I would add this.

The functions inside the NumericArrayUtilities` package AFAIK are helper functions that are primarily of use to those developing new machine learning functionality and applications.

To see a list:

```
?NumericArrayUtilities`*
```

Doing this for **any** package will produce a nicely formatted grid of clickable links for each function in the package, that will (depending on output format!) look something like:

```
InformationDataGrid[{
    "ctx`" -> {
        "ctx`myFunctionName, ...
}}, ___]
```

if you are in input form, something slightly more terse in full form, or in a notebook,

[image: A formatted InformationDataGrid[...]]

Caveat: YMMV with subpackages and namespaces, etc... Grepping the function names in certain packages will also produce output that is extremely voluminous.

Comment: I asked about a package specifically for performing fast arithmetic operations on the `NumericArray` objects. Can you show, how this package can be used for this?